# Switch color of all elements with JS/Jquery when page contains certain URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can change certain color on the website in all elements (span, div, h1, h2 etc.) when URL contains certain string?

I have following piece of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("/STRING/") > -1) {
      console.log("CONTAINS STRING");
    
    }
})
```

But I can't find a way to change the color everywhere. I've only found methods to change it in certain elements like divs and spans.

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for actually changing the colors. Define the color in CSS and only apply a class with JS to `body` or `html` that will then actually change the colors.

Comment: Color is already defined in CSS, however there are over 150+ elements to modify. It includes text colors, buttons backgrounds, div borders etc. I think it would be faster just to find in the html certain string like #FAFAFA and change it to #c4c4c4.

Comment: It definitely wont be easier then to use a well structured CSS setup, but go ahead and give it a shot ;) -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Wrap all your content in a wrapper. And add class with Js only when conditions are met.

Comment: Copy your .css file, find all the colour entries you want to change, remove everything else, change the colour (in the css copy).   Either:  in your css copy, prefix every rule with ".alt" then include both css files and add `$("body").addClass("alt")`  *or*  don't prefix and only include the css when you want to change the colours.

Comment: Classic XY problem...   "*think it would be faster just to find in the html certain string*" ... you thought wrong.  :)  (it's not in the html)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define one css class and use it in each tag you want.
But if you insist on using javascript you can try this one:

```js
function change(){
        var alltag = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (var i = 0; i < alltag.length; i++) {
            if (alltag[i].style.color == "red" /*or such condition you want*/)
               alltag[i].style.color = "green"
        }
}
```

```html
<div style="color:red">this is DIV Tag 1</div>

    <a style="color:red" href="#">this is anchor tag 1</a>
    
    <button onclick="change()"> chnage the red to green color</button>
```

Comment: _"**find** in the html **certain string like #FAFAFA** and change it to #c4c4c4"_

Comment: His question is about all `Tag`

Comment: Yes, but only with a specific color, which will make this so much more difficult to solve with JS

Comment: I mentioned that this is not best way. and It's better to use css class

Comment: Yes, it's better to use css, and yes, you've provided *a* js solution, as requested - however, this will change *all* elements to `red` (as per title), not just the ones that are a specific colour (as per actual question).